# Using Zend Search Lucene with Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, zend-search-lucene

I have a searchform in my webapp where users can search others by name, clubname, ...
This is the code I'm using for the search but it's not giving me any 'hits'.

```
$search = $this->get('ewz_search.lucene');

$query = new MultiTerm();
$query->addTerm(new Term($form->getData()->getName()));
$query->addTerm(new Term($form->getData()->getClub()->getId()));

// See point 1 to see what this displays
var_dump($query);

// See point 2 to see what this displays
die("debug: " . $query);

// If I use this instead of the MultiTerm, I do get a hit
// $query = 'Mathew';

$hits = $search->find($query);
```

Point 1:
object(Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm)#644 (9) { ["_terms":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\Term)#638 (2) { ["field"]=> NULL ["text"]=> string(12) "Mathew" } [1]=> object(Zend\Search\Lucene\Index\Term)#637 (2) { ["field"]=> NULL ["text"]=> int(1) } } ["_signs":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL } ["_resVector":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> NULL ["_termsFreqs":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> array(0) { } ["_coord":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> NULL ["_weights":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\MultiTerm":private]=> array(0) { } ["_boost":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\AbstractQuery":private]=> int(1) ["_weight":protected]=> NULL ["_currentColorIndex":"Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\AbstractQuery":private]=> int(0) }

Point 2: 
debug: Mathew 1

Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Check the default term operator. If you have separate field indexes for clubid and name you can prefix the field name.

`$query = "name:Mathew AND clubid:1";`

See the [parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html) for more information.

Comment: Thx for your input. I thought I was good to go until I started testing with a query that should give more than one result. I have this MultiTerm query that prints: "+name: +club:A.R.A. LA GANTOISE +natranking: +doublesranking:" (which doesn't give any results) and I tried doing it manually like $query="+name: +club:A.R.A. LA GANTOISE +natranking: +doublesranking:" (this works) .. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
I had this:

```
$document->addField(Field::text('Name', $user->getName()));
```

Instead of:

```
$document->addField(Field::text('name', $user->getName()));
```